# Hash(m1 xor m2) = Hash(m1) xor Hash (m2) Is this true in case of SHA1

Tags: hash, cryptography

Can anyone shed some knowledge on this?

My answer is no, it is not true, because SHA1 has a strong collision resistant property.

Comment: You can easily verify this fact yourself.

Comment: But, I know how to compute hash for a file not a stream, how do I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No this isn't true. (And it would only take a few seconds to actually test it yourself.)

Comment: I know how to find a hash of a file but not a hash on command line. How can one find hash of a number or a string instead of a file?

Comment: @Ringo: Not sure, maybe something like `sha1sum --string=hello`.

Comment: man sha1sum gave me only 3 type of arguments, none for anything other than files. :(

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not true. A function would have to go out of its way to have this property. SHA1 incorporates bytes from its stream on block at a time starting with a predefined initial value. At the end it incorporates the length of the byte stream into the byte stream and pads out to the block size.

It makes no attempt to satisfy the property in question (which is a good thing!)

Answer (score 1):

No. To [quote from Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-1):

> Even a small change in the message will, with overwhelming probability, result in a completely different hash due to the avalanche effect.

Here's a counterexample (0xFF xor 0x00 is 0xFF):

```
$ echo -ne "\xff" > 1
$ echo -ne "\x00" > 2
$ sha1sum *
85e53271e14006f0265921d02d4d736cdc580b0b *1
5ba93c9db0cff93f52b521d7420e43f6eda2784f *2
```

If your statement were true, the second hash would have to be 00000000..., but it is not.

Comment: But where I got doubt is

DES also exhibit avalanche effect also exhibit Complementation property
     
E_K(P)=C \Leftrightarrow E_\overline{K}(\overline{P})=\overline{C}

Answer (score 0):

I'm affraid this will hold only if your hash function is XOR.

Comment: It will hold for any linear function over F_2, the finite field of two elements, not just XOR.

Comment: @GregS `(A ^ B) + 1 != (A + 1) ^ (B + 1)` . Can you explain what you mean?

Comment: take any [CRC](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Cyclic_redundancy_check): CRC(A xor B) = CRC(A) xor CRC(B). The CRC is not just an XOR.